# Resizable frameless Window

Tags: c++, windows, qt5

I have a frameless Qt Window. I am using custom buttons to restore down or maximize the window. I want the user to be able to resize the window when the window is restored down. To achieve that, I referred to the answer in the following post:

[Qt/Windows, resizable frameless window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43505580/qt-windows-resizable-frameless-window)

Now the problem I'm facing is that the window resize handles are not appearing when I try to resize the window in restore down state.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found my answer in this post.

[How to implement QSizeGrip in a Qt frameless window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139559/how-to-implement-qsizegrip-in-a-qt-frameless-window)

I added & removed the QSizeGrip widget when Restoring down & maximizing my window.